# Fire event after datatables table finishes rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using datatables and fetching the data from an ajax URL. Each row of my returned table data includes a field that renders a button that looks like this:

```
<button type="button" data-catid="8" data-catname="Programming:JavaScript"></button>
```

The values assigned data-catid and data-catname come from the datatables retrieved data.

In certain cases, when the table finishes loading, I want to trigger a click on one of these buttons. My code for that is this:

```
$('#mydatatable').find('button[data-catid="9"]').trigger('click');
```

However, I cannot find a way to do this so that it occurs after the table has rendered and the button exists in the dom so I can find it and trigger the click.

I have tried drawCallback and initComplete but neither of those is triggered after the button has actually been added to the dom, allowing me to find it with jquery.

Is there a way I can do this? i.e. trigger my click after the mytable has finished retrieving its data via ajax and rendered it?

I am using datatables v 1.10

EDIT: 
Here is how my click event handler is attached to the summary table.

```
var selectedCat = 0;
$('#mydatatable :button').click(function () {
    selectedCat = this.getAttribute("data-catId");
    console.log("selecteCat is " + selectedCat);
    qDetailTable.ajax.url('/datatables/question-data/' + selectedCat).load();
    var selectedCatName = this.getAttribute("data-catName");
    $('#questDetailCat').text('Questions about: ' + selectedCatName);
    $('#questSummary').hide();
    $('#questDetail').show();
});
```

Comment: What if button with `data-catid="9"` is not visible on screen, i.e. on page 2, do you want to trigger a click when data has been loaded or when user goes to page 2? Also it would be important to see how you attach your click event handler.

Comment: That is  good question re page 2, though paging is client side. Basically this page has 2 datatables, one is a summary table and the other a detail table and either one or the other shows. If you click on a summary table row it opens the detail for that category. I am trying to make it so that when a user is returned to this page from elsewhere, if they last were looking at the detail panel, then that's the panel which will be displayed. I will edit my question to show the click event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Move the click handler into a separate function, for example:

  ```
  var selectedCat = 0;
  function OnCategoryClick(btn){
      selectedCat = btn.getAttribute("data-catId");
      console.log("selecteCat is " + selectedCat);
      qDetailTable.ajax.url('/datatables/question-data/' + selectedCat).load();
      var selectedCatName = btn.getAttribute("data-catName");
      $('#questDetailCat').text('Questions about: ' + selectedCatName);
      $('#questSummary').hide();
      $('#questDetail').show();
  });
  ```

  Event handler needs to be in a named function because you will not be able to trigger click event for elements that are not in DOM as with jQuery DataTables.
- Change how you attach your click handler.

  ```
  $('#mydatatable').on('click', 'button', function () {
      OnCategoryClick(this); 
  });
  ```

  Remember to always use delegated event handlers with elements inside jQuery DataTables because elements for pages other than first will not be available in DOM. See [jQuery DataTables – Why click event handler does not work](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-why-click-event-handler-does-not-work/) for more details.
- Use [`$()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24%28%29) API method to locate required button and call your handler function `OnCategoryClick()`.

  ```
  var btn = $('#datatable-summary').DataTable().$('button[data-catid="9"]').get(0);         
  OnCategoryClick(btn);
  ```

  Replace `datatable-summary`  with your actual ID of the summary table.

  If you need to update details as soon as the summary table is initialized and drawn, use [`initComplete`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) option to define a callback and do it there.

Comment: Thank you so much - one problem I still have is that in the var btn = line I want to assign a variable value to data-catid so data-catid=myvar instead of data-catid = "9"   but I cannot seem to find the right syntax for doing that. Can you advise?

Comment: The data-catid attribute is already set on all the buttons. I need jquery to fetch the button with data-catid=myvar.

Comment: Last bullet point shows the code to get the button with `data-catid="9"`. Use `$('#datatable-summary').DataTable().$('button[data-catid="' + myvar + '"]')` if category ID is in the variable.

Comment: this does helped me.